# Its so strange to use constructor just like a function, is it normal?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

It is a constructor, so a new instance of the vector appears. Does this mean that it needs to be deleted or will it be automatically deleted after addition is complete?

```
struct vect
{
   vect() {}
   vect(vect a, vect b, double Force) {}
};

int main()
{
   vect b, c; 
   double d;

   vect k = a + vect(b, c, d);
}
```

*(Presume `a` and the addition feature are declared elsewhere.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Despite appearances, this is *not* "using a constructor like a function".**

It is actually a cast, [using something called "functional cast notation"](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type.conv#1).

It takes one or more values (in this case `b`, `c` and `d`) and makes a `vect` out of them.

Yes, this will involve invoking the `vect(vect, vect, double)` constructor for you behind the scenes; it has to. But that's not the only thing involved in creating an object, if only conceptually. All those other things combine to *give you a real, breathing object*, which exists within all the normal scope rules.

So, no, you won't get a memory leak.

It is, in fact, impossible to "call a constructor like a function", because [constructors have no names](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor#1.sentence-2). There is simply no syntax to do that, though the syntax for delegating constructors is close.

However, this common misconception arguably doesn't really matter very much in practice, as long as you don't start thinking you're managing to somehow skip the other parts of object creation (such as making memory for it) like you did in your question.

**The colloquial term for what you're doing would be "creating a temporary" and, yes, it's completely normal.**

Since it's a temporary (i.e. an unnamed variable), it's automatically destroyed at the end of the statement (formally, at the end of the *full-expression* in which it was created). However, presumably your `+` operation has already copied it or whatever by then.

Comment: I used it for a long time, but today I felt that it was somehow strange, although undoubtedly something like this happens every time I write "a + 3" ... This is a strange feeling

Comment: @Kelbon Pour a stiff drink and you'll be okay ;)